How do i extract tables in the most efficient way using?
I have been using pdfplumber since. Is there any other library? apart from camelot, which uses pypdf2 and now theres an error saying:
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_utils.py", line 369, in deprecation_with_replacement
    deprecation(DEPR_MSG_HAPPENED.format(old_name, removed_in, new_name))
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_utils.py", line 351, in deprecation
    raise DeprecationError(msg)

PyPDF2.errors.DeprecationError: PdfFileReader is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use PdfReader instead.
so what other way exists thanks!
I tried using pdfplumber, which is the current working solution but it doesnt read some pdf tables well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I mostly use tabula-py: https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/
A wrapper around an enclosed java jarfile from https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula
>>> import tabula
>>> f = "https://annex.exploratorium.edu/ronh/solar_system/scale.pdf"
>>> df = tabula.read_pdf(f, stream=True)
'pages' argument isn't specified.Will extract only from page 1 by default.
>>> df[0].head()
         Planet  Distance  Unnamed: 0   Distance to Scale distance        Actual
0           NaN  from Sun         NaN        planet       from Sun      diameter
1           NaN      (AU)         NaN  (kilometers)  (centimeters)  (kilometers)
2  Sun (a star)         0         NaN           NaN            NaN     1,391,980
3       Mercury      0.39         NaN    58,000,000            NaN         4,880
4         Venus      0.72         NaN   108,000,000            NaN        12,100

It creates a list of dataframes and you can use local files as well.
